# How to minimize error?

Tags: calculus

How would I find all the values that minimizes an error expression?

For example, if there is an expression (x-a)^2 + (x-b)^2+ (x-c)^2+ (x-d)^2 with the values of a = 3.1, b = 3.3, c = 3.6, d = 3.9 and I want to find all the real values of x that minimize this equation, how would I approach this?

Comment: Take the derivative and set it to zero.  It will be the average of the four points.

Comment: So I plug in all the values of a, b, c, and d into the equation, set it to zero, take the derivative and solve for x and that x is the value that minimizes the error?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Why does it work when I set the derivative to 0? Why not the original equation? Could I also graph the original equation and then look for the x value that has the minimum point on the graph?

Comment: @mathlife assuming you have something to plot it, you can find the minimum just by inspection, though this would make it hard to get a high precision result.

Comment: @Tyberius I tried to plot this on an online graphing calculator and it wouldn't graph. I am confused on how I can find multiple values that minimizes the expression...

Comment: It was able to be plotted here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-3.1%29%5E2%2B%28x-3.3%29%5E2%2B%28x-3.6%29%5E2%2B%28x-3.9%29%5E2 . It looks like the minimum is about 3.5 and it shows the actual minimum further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum or maximum will come at a point where the slope of the tangent is zero.  It is turning around from being increasing to decreasing (or the other way around).  This is why you take the derivative and set it to zero.  Yes, you can graph the original equation and look for the $x$ value that gives the minimum.  That will give you an approximate answer.  This is true for all differentiable functions, not just error ones.  It should have been part of your calculus I class.